# Access to the requested URL within a Django handler404 redirection?

Tags: django, view, http-status-code-404, handler

*I am sure this has a trivially easy answer but I have spent a couple of hours with Google and Stack Overflow without finding any answer.*

I am building a Django CMS for a multi-language web site. URLS take the form:

```
https://example.com/xx/subject
```

where x is a two-letter code for a language (en=English, fr=French). For example:

```
https://example.com/en/about-us
https://example.com/fr/a-propos
```

**I need to be able to access the requested URL from within the handler404 view to provide appropriate content to the visitor.**

I currently have a working 404 redirect in the Django app:

*project.urls.py*

```
handler404 = 'myapp.views.error404'
```

*myapp.views.py*

```
def PageView(request, lang, subject):
    [creates a page with DB content based on lang & subject]

def error404(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return PageView(request,'en','404page',)
```

**I would like to know what the requested URL was** in order to redirect the visitor to a page in their language.

Under this system the 404 page will be a page in the CMS like any other, so it will be editable by the CMS user (I am not using Django templates to create pages).

**There will be one "404page" entry in the DB for each language.**

Here is a non-working example of the kind of thing I'm looking for:

```
def error404(request, *args, **kwargs):
    lang = args[0]
    subject = args[1]
    if lang = 'fr':
        return PageView(request,'fr','error404',)
    else:
        return PageView(request,'en','error404',)
```

If someone requests **example.com/fr/quelque-chose**, I want to show them content from **fr/404Page**.

If someone requests **example.com/mlkqdjsf** or **example.com/en/not-a-page**, I want to show them content from **en/404page**.

In both cases I will be using the **PageView** view that I use to construct the regular site pages.

Comment: Do you know about `request.path` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with `request.path`:

```
def error404(request, *args, **kwargs):
    lang = request.path.split('/')[1]
    if lang = 'fr':
        return PageView(request,'fr','error404',)
    else:
        return PageView(request,'en','error404',)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the language,  you can use `get_language_from_request` function:

```
from django.utils import translation

def error404(request, *args, **kwargs):
    language = translation.get_language_from_request(request, check_path=True)
    return PageView(request, language, 'error404')
```

The `check_path` argument is to check first if the URL begins with a language code, which I think is what you want.

Check the django documentation about the [`get_language_from_request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language_from_request) and other translation related functions.